# How to select a dropdown list element using webdriver selenium in python where it is of input type?

Tags: python, html, selenium, automated-tests

The HTML script is :

```
    <input id="ctl00_TableContentPlaceHolder_ddlAssignedTo_input" 
    type="text" class="selectbox" autocomplete="off" readonly="" 
    tabindex="0" style="width: 325px;">

    <ul id="the_list">
    <li id="ctl00_TableContentPlaceHolder_ddlAssignedTo_input_-1" 
    class="">Please Select</li>
    <li id="ctl00_TableContentPlaceHolder_ddlAssignedTo_input_18">john</li>
    <li id="ctl00_TableContentPlaceHolder_ddlAssignedTo_input_20">erine</li>
    <li id="ctl00_TableContentPlaceHolder_ddlAssignedTo_input_22">devin</li>
```

Here the user will give the name like john , erine or devin and i have to select that item from the list .Using selenium web driver in python 2.7 .

Here's my progress till now :

```
   import selenium
   from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
   from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
   elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*
   [@id="ctl00_TableContentPlaceHolder_ddlAssignedTo_input"]')
   elem.send_keys(name)
```

Comment: Can you update the Question with a snapshot of the Element you are referring to. From the HTML you shared it seems to have an `<input>` tag and a `<ul>` tag as well. Also consider providing the complete `HTML` of the `<input>` tag. The main question is, is it mandatory to `send_keys` to the `<input>` tag for the `<li>` elements to showup/expand?

Comment: Drop down with attribute as text?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not that clear from your Question if it mandatory to use **`send_keys()`** to the **`<input>`** tag for the **`<li>`** elements to showup/expand. Assuming it as a `False Positive`, to select a dropdown list element you can write a function as below :

```
def select_option(option):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@id='the_list']/li[contains(.,'" + option + "')]").click()
```

Comment: it's not necessary to use send_keys

Comment: @SunilPatra Great !!! I have modified the code block as per your comment that `it's not necessary to use send_keys`. **Upvote** the/any `Answer` if this/any `Answer` is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to click drop-down first and then list item.

```
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="the_list"]')
elem.click()

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[text()=' + name + ']')
elem.click()
```

Comment: No response , Error message :  raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible

Comment: also mention how to select an element

Comment: @SunilPatra can you check updated snippet?

Comment: No response at all .  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible

Comment: not even a click